# What is the impact when openning hundreds of database connections from Service Fabric?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-service-fabric

We have got around 800 on-premise customers with databases (MS-SQL and Oracle) ranging from 20 to 400 GB. My team is architecting an Azure version and I would like to get some advice.

Our idea is to use Azure SQL Server. Every customer (tenant) will get its own database. This is important as the customers can decide if they want to update to a newer version or not. I know it sounds strange for a cloud software but for their FDA compliance they need to validate any new version and this can take weeks for them. This means we could have two or three "active" vesions and - for example - 30% of the customers with V1, 60% with V2 and 10% with V3.

The business server will be implemented using Service Fabric so that we can scale when we get new cloud customers. At any point in time we will have these 2 or 3 versions of our software in the clusters. The tenants will then connect to the right "logic" and the servers will then connect to the customer's database.

And now to my question: could this work? I mean, the machines in the cluster will need to connect to maybe 300 different databases. The connection pool on-prem uses the connection string and the user as key for reusing the connections. We hope that the cloud works somehow differently and will not be limited by the number of different connections. Does it use pools at all? If it does, what is the impact? (memory, performance, ...)

Any other ideas about implementing it?

Comment: You might have more luck posting this question on [Stack DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).  If you agree you can move by clicking *flag* >> *should be closed* >> *off-topic* >> *belongs on another stack site*.

Comment: Why would you have any problem with connection pooling on-prem? This sounds like a design problem - why would you want to use a *different account's* credentials to connect to another's database? Are you keeping connections and transactions open too long perhaps?

Comment: Hallo Panagiotis, we wouldn't use different account credentials for the databases, but you are connecting to 300 different databases. This means 300 different connection strings, even if you connect with the same fixed credentials. The pool needs in this case at least a size of 300 entries (much more if you want to get any improvement from the pool).

Comment: @Raul What did you end up doing? Did you have problems with pool fragmentation?

Comment: Sorry @MattJacobi, I didn't get the notification about your question. We dropped the project :-( We had some proof of concepts and prototypes, but the business case was not so clear. The costs for all the different clusters with all the different versions and databases made it too risky. The project was started as "research", but as we had no customers as stakeholder (read noone asked for it) we stopped it.

Answer (score 1):

[Connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) works the same on prem as in the cloud. Connections are pooled by connection string. You can connect to as many databases as you want.

Have a look at [Azure Sql elastic pools](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-pool/) for a way to manage many databases in the cloud in a cost effective manner.

Comment: Thank you LoekD. Yes, I know how connection pooling in general works. Exactly the problem under "Pool Fragmentation Due to Many Databases" on your link is what worries us. If we connect to 300 different database we will need a pool with 300 x SomeNumber connections! Let's say the pool should be able to reuse at least 10 connections per database. This would be 3,000 entries!!! How would this impact the performance? Even if we used elastic pools, we will be accessing different databases. I thought that maybe Azure SQL used another strategy for the connections.

Comment: It's ADO.NET that keeps the pool. It runs in the caller process, not inside Azure SQL. Can't you connect to master and then do 'USE databasename' as suggested?

Comment: I think the pool is something that every database provider manages itself. This is the reason we hope that maybe a provider for Azure SQL could be different than the normal SQL Server one.